# Como utilizar parámetros en informe que acepte varios valores, utilizando Reportviewer

Tags: c#, sql-server, reportviewer, reportviewerreporte, informes

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL SERVER, que se genero utilizando la herramienta conjunto de datos y haciendo al mismo tiempo la conexión, Como ven la consulta, tiene un IN, para que al introducir un valor pueda introducir otro. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi código lo tengo la siguiente manera para que llame ese valor y lo pueda introducir en el texto el valor que quiera llamar, si funciona pero, pero solo llama un solo valor si quiero introducir otro ya no funciona el reporte
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro como mandarle varios valores, o sea buscar varios periodos solo recibe una periodo y la busca bien, pero como puedo desde c# mandarle varios valores? desde el TextBox creo que el procedimiento esta bien ¿pero desde c# como los mando? seria como poner esto en el TextBox Periodo1, Periodo2 pero solo trae uno no los dos
Alguna sugerencia que me pueda compartir para que funcione.

Comment: Puedes probar creando un arreglo preguntado si lo que hay en tu caja de texto contiene espacio o coma, de esa manera separas los string por coma y podras hacer lo que buscas :)

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo ya lo probé con arrays pero no me funciono, lo hice de la siguiente manera

Answer (score 0):

@Franqo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice un for para el array

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues al ultimo con Buttonclic lo traigo a llamar esos valores que tiene el array, alguna sugerencia que me falte o pueda hacer diferente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para la proxima, con el fin de que la ayuda sea mas sencilla, por favor escribe el codigo con su formato correcto en vez de añadir fotos, el codigo es mas legible y se puede copiar y pegar.